# can i use protobuf-c both in C++ and C?

Tags: c++, c

i'm new one to protobuf-c 
  i have altered protobuf-c client and server example program as per my requirement and i got this program through this link

> [code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/wiki/RPC_Example](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/wiki/RPC_Example)

now i have to write server side programing in c++ and i want to use the client side program in c itself this my new requirement

can any one  please help me how to use the .h and .c proto file that is compiled using protobuf-c in c++ server side program file
any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Why don’t you use the C++ protobuf library for the server side? You *can* use the C library but why would you? That makes it unnecessarily hard.

Comment: The main idea of the protobuf library is to provide a way to exchange messages across language barriers. You can decode and encode messages in C, C++, Java and Python (plus a lot of other languages which provide wrappers) and don't have to worry about the language used at the other end.

Comment: Thank you Rudolf.  but i'm using protoc-c to compile the proto file and that will generate structures and methods for messages and Enums. if we use protoc to compile the proto file it will generate classes so my point is how can we use the same compiled proto file...

Comment: can one any please clarify my doubt

Comment: Hi matthieu, you are right but my doubt is, how can we use the compiled protofile in different languages with protobuf-c

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @Konrad Rudolph, the entire point of protobuf is to use same message format with different languages.
So, you do the following:

1. Write your .proto file
2. Compile this .proto file with protobuf-c for client code and with protobuf (protoc) for server code (that would be different classes, but same message format!)
3. Link client code to protobuf-c and server code to protobuf

This will resolve your issue.